# How to add categories to products in woocommerce programatically?

Tags: categories, plugins

I have studies the database intensively and know which all tables are updated when a category is added to a product. Is there any inbuilt woocommerce function to add categories? It updates  2 or 3 tables but want to leave it to woocommerce.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you tried with `wp_set_object_terms` ?

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to do? Woo's "product categories" are really just a custom taxonomy ( product_cat ) and adrian's suggestion would work fine.

Answer (score 5):

I think the function you are looking for is called [wp_insert_term()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) in WordPress core.
Woocommerce uses WordPress-taxonomy called `product_cat`

So if you want to add some categories for example `phones`:

```
function wpse_insert_term()
{
    wp_insert_term(
      'phones',
      'product_cat', // the taxonomy
      array(
        'description'=> 'A yummy phone.',
        'slug' => 'phone',
      )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'wpse_insert_term');
```